# Learning! Pick a dictionary from within a dictionary and adjust with user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
users = {
    'maxwell': {},
    'kimberly': {},
    'zoe': {},
    }

#  user name selector that repeats till a viable username
end = False

    while end is False:

    user_select = input('What is your name: ')
    if user_select.lower() in users:
        end = True
        print('Welcome ' + str(user_select.title()) + '! Lets get started!')

    else:
        print('User name not found')

#  start adding favorite items to their dictionary.

user_select['color'] = input('What is your favorite color:  ')
user_select['food'] = input('What is your favorite food: ')
```

So this is my code so far and it obviously doesn't work. I am still working through the book I bought to teach myself Python, so telling me to "quit skipping ahead and programming over your head" is a viable response. I just like challenging myself. If not, maybe y'all can help!

So lets say maxwell signs on and gets past the 'while' section and begins to answer questions. What can I put in for "user_select" in the last lines of code that can become whatever name they pick and start adding items to their dictionary? I was going to have them add themselves to the dictionary to begin with but that seemed even harder, so I started with a select few.

My thought process behind this would be a teacher acquiring info from their students after already entering their names into the dictionary.

This question I'm sure has already been asked, I'm just new enough I don't know the name of what I'm trying to do. Also, is this where I'm supposed to ask questions like this? Is there a more beginner appropriate website for learners like me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're about 95% of the way there, nice job!

First, your main question: in order to update the `maxwell` dictionary, you need to get it from `users` and then use the standard `dict[key] = value` syntax to modify its contents. Your code isn't working because you're attempting that dictionary access on `user_select` - a string.

Re-writing the last couple lines like this does the trick:

```
user_dict = users[user_select.lower()]  # get the dictionary associated with the entered username
user_dict['color'] = input('What is your favorite color:  ')  # add keys to that dictionary
user_dict['food'] = input('What is your favorite food: ')
```

Now if you print out the `users` dictionary you'll see this:

```
users = {
    'maxwell': {
        'color': 'red',
        'food': 'pizza'},
    'kimberly': {},
    'zoe': {}}
```

---

As an alternative, dynamically adding users to the main `users` dictionary would simplify your code quite a bit:

```
users = {}

user_name = input("What is your name: ")
print("Welcome {}! Let's get started!".format(user_name))

users[user_name.lower()] = user_dict = {}
user_dict['color'] = input('What is your favorite color:  ')
user_dict['food'] = input('What is your favorite food: ')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Dynamically adding to the users dictionary was what I originally had in mind but I couldn't figure out how to do it. It turns out both are solved with the same `user_dict` idea. Thanks!